# How to Get block 'head' description in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, blocks, meta-tags, head

In magento 1.9 i can get the page head description like this in phtml:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getDescription()
```

How can i achieve this in Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

In magento2, if you want to  get meta description at phtml then you have to call `Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config`.

As you want to use this value in  `phtml`, then i suggest to use [**view model**](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/view-models.html)

Create View model  class  `Description.php` at Your module `app/code/VendorName/Modulename/ViewModel` and inject `Config` class and  get description on phtml.

**Example:**

```
<?php
namespace StackExchange\SampleModule\ViewModel;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config;

class Description implements ArgumentInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    private $pageConfig;

    public function __construct(Config $pageConfig)
    {
        $this->pageConfig = $pageConfig;
    }
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->pageConfig->getDescription();
    }
}
```

Assume  that your  phtml called at product  detail page then and  phtml called in layout as name "mycustom.block" and then create `catalog_product_view.xml`  at  `app/code/VendorName/Modulename/view/frontend/layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="mycustom.block">
                    <argument name="view_model_description" xsi:type="object">StackExchange\SampleModule\ViewModel\Description</argument>
                </arguments>

        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Last step:  access the view model class  at your phtml file**

```
<?php

/** @var $viewModelDescription \StackExchange\SampleModule\ViewModel\Description */

$viewModelDescription = $block->getViewModelDescription();

echo $viewModelDescription->getDescription();
?>
```